# How to use QList with std::generate?

Tags: c++, stl, qlist, qvector

I ran a test to compare `QVector` and `QList` insertions/sorting  performance with this code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

#include <QVector>
#include <QList>

int  main()
{
  constexpr auto  size = 10000000ul;

  srand(time(nullptr));

  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {
    std::cout << "First test with QVector<int>" << std::endl;
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _g;
    QVector<int>                  vector(size);

    {
      std::cout << "\t Generating:" << std::endl << "\t\t";
      boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _;

      std::generate(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector), []
      {
        return clock() % rand();
      });
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    {
      std::cout << "\t Sorting:" << std::endl << "\t\t";
      boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _;

      std::sort(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {
    std::cout << "Second test with QList<int>" << std::endl;
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _g;
    QList<int>                    list;
    list.reserve(size);

    {
      std::cout << "\t Generating:" << std::endl << "\t\t";
      boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _;

      std::generate(std::begin(list), std::end(list), []
      {
        return clock() % rand();
      });
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    {
      std::cout << "\t Sorting:" << std::endl << "\t\t";
      boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer  _;

      std::sort(std::begin(list), std::end(list));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**One possible output:**

```sh
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

First test with QVector<int>
     Generating:
         5.544336s wall, 3.240000s user + 2.250000s system = 5.490000s CPU (99.0%)

     Sorting:
         2.593883s wall, 2.550000s user + 0.010000s system = 2.560000s CPU (98.7%)

 8.157371s wall, 5.790000s user + 2.280000s system = 8.070000s CPU (98.9%)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Second test with QList<int>
     Generating:
         0.000001s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)

     Sorting:
         0.000001s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)

 0.000060s wall, 0.000000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.000000s CPU (n/a%)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I reserve memory with `QList<int>::reserve` function, and use `std::generate` to generate random number and insert it to `QList` variable. But it do nothing because of `QList` is always empty.

How could i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [`reserve`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#reserve) only allocates memory, but it doesn't set the size.

You can `reserve` any amount, but the size will still be zero.

There's no [`QList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) function to actually set the size.

However you might be able to use e.g. the [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) iterator adapter function to append elements to the list. Combine this with the `reserve` and the list shouldn't have to allocate new memory. Though you can't use it with `std::generate`, use [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) instead:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(list), size, []
{
    return clock() % rand();
});
```